# getResourceAsStream() return null in Eclipse, but not always

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream

I am so incredibly confused by this. I've struggled with this before, but once I figured it out, I didn't really have any more problems. But now, it's shown up again. Basically, I have some code which reads a file in as an Image. However, only certain images are readable. Specifically, I can only access images which have been added to the project folder after I refactored to include all files in the source folder (they had previously been outside, but still included in the JAR). I've since managed to fix it by creating copies of the problem folders, deleting the originals, then effectively renaming the copies to the same name as the originals, but I'm still curious as to why this would happen. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Well `getResourceAsStream` looks for stuff on your classpath, so if you want to read images which are not on the classpath, you should use a different method.

Comment: Or, put another way, you can add folders to your eclipse build path (even if they don't contain Java files), and then resources in that directory will be available to the `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Agreed with @rolfl, you can add any folder to your classpath and you can have the image in a jar too.

Comment: So basically, the images weren't automatically added to the classpath by Eclipse when I refactored, but they were once I recopied? Seems rather confusing that they would be added the second time around.

Answer (score 1):

One should verify the jar by opening it with 7zip, Winzip or so.

In the same jar, a class can use `getResourceAsStream` with an URL (path separator `/`, not `\\`). A relative URL when the image is in the same package or subpackage path. An absolute URL `"/..."` otherwise.

Important is that the path is *case-sensitive* - not as Windows file names. This can be tricky, as if the file also is on the class path outside the jar, then on Windows (but not Linux) a wrong case will seem okay.